# Apache FOP insert special character

Tags: apache-fop

I generate PDF files by using FOP, but some Polish characters are not displayed and an error is displayed:

> Glyph "ś" (0x15b, sacute) not available in font "Helvetica".

How can I fix that?

Comment: You must use (and configure properly) a font having that special character. For a quick check, if you can write "ś" in your editor of choice (Word, OpenOffice, ...) and find a font that visualizes it properly.

Comment: thanx @ifurini it was helpful